# any method to change/instrument class loaded in bootclassloader in latest sun jre

Tags: java

needs: 
we need to hack one class in plugin.jar, in detail, change one class's non static method's detail implementation. as in latest jre , -Xbootclasspath/p  doesn't work  and only -Xbootclasspath/a works. also we don't want to change whole jre.

We know our last solution is to change the plugin.jar file directly. But want to know if there is some better solution which don't need to change the jar file directly.

for example, don't know if things like  JVMTI or JVMPI will work? OR somehow change JVM's imple in an easy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

depends on your class, but you could probably use a **javaagent** to inject a custom ClassFileTransformer that loads a different class, if queried... (simple [example](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/) on javaagents). But this only works, if the class was not loaded before...

Comment: we want to hack class "sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader", already using javasist to try to hack it combine with java agent  now. not sure whether it will work. still checking...

Comment: it works....  I already thinking this before, but wrm's answer make me more confident and after more experiments. it works great!